# Discord.py Disable Module Command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I made a "disable module" which is working, but when it loads into a json file I get a error message.

```
@client.command(aliases=["disable economy"])   
async def disable_economy(message): 
    with open('disable economy.json', 'r+') as f:
        channel = json.load(f)
        if not f'{message.channel.id}' in channel:
            channel[f'{message.channel.id}'] = "Channel ID"
            json.dump(channel, f)
            await message.channel.send(f"Economy has been disabled in <#{message.channel.id}>. ")
            return
        if f'{message.channel.id}' in channel:
            await message.channel.send("Economy is already disabled in this channel.")
            return
```

After doing the command it loads into a json file like this:
`{}{"750485129436201023": "Channel ID"}` and the error message I get is: `End of file expected`. The error is between the 2nd {. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}{"750485129436201023": "Channel ID"}` is not valid JSON.

Valid JSON can only have one root element, such as `{}`

Change your JSON file to just:

```
{"750485129436201023": "Channel ID"}
```

Python is appending to the file, instead of overwriting it, the easiest way to fix this is to `seek` to the beginning of the file before writing:

```
f.seek(0)
json.dump(channel, f)
```

Comment: Yea that works but when I do the command again, it stores in the json file like this: ``{"739683588408082465": "Channel ID"}{"739683588408082465": "Channel ID", "750485129436201023": "Channel ID"}`` and i get the same error message

Comment: @drew Thank you!